# Convert QString to unsigned short int

Tags: c++, qt

I need to take a QString (for example "A") and transform this string to 0x41.
The input is a QString and the output must be a "WORD" (microsoft stuff).

a WORD is a unsigned short int in my case.
I have tried :

```
Qstring str = "A"
qDebug() << str.toLatin1().toHex().prepend("0x");
```

the result is good "0x41" but it's not a unsigned short int :( i have tried cast, but it doesn't work.

the commun answer seem use "toUShort" but my code doesn't work with this change.
I want emulate a keyboard with the dll winuser (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

this code work :

```
INPUT key;
key.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
key.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
key.ki.time = 0;
key.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

key.ki.wVk = 0x42; // virtual-key code for the "a" key

key.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
SendInput(1, &key, sizeof(INPUT));
key.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
SendInput(1, &key, sizeof(INPUT));
```

that no :

```
QString str = "a";
bool ok;

INPUT key;
key.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
key.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
key.ki.time = 0;
key.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

key.ki.wVk = str.toUShort(&ok,16);

key.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
SendInput(1, &key, sizeof(INPUT));
key.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
SendInput(1, &key, sizeof(INPUT));
```

maybe it's just because short return 42 and not 0x42.

-- SOLUTION --

```
void SyncKeyboard::writeUID(QString uid)
{
    qDebug() << uid;

    for(int i = 0; i < uid.length(); i++)
        pressKey(uid.at(i).unicode());
}

void SyncKeyboard::pressKey(ushort letter)
{
    INPUT key;
    key.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    key.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
    key.ki.time = 0;
    key.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    key.ki.wVk = letter;
    key.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
    SendInput(1, &key, sizeof(INPUT));
    key.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
    SendInput(1, &key, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Comment: Show your cast, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to get a unsigned short int, namely the hexadecimal ASCII code from `A`, you can try to use [QByteArray::toUShort](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#toUShort) instead.

```
ushort QByteArray::toUShort ( bool * ok = 0, int base = 16 ) const
```

Comment: i have tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work, maybe i dont use correctly the method... (i have edited my question )

Comment: You cannot call `toUShort()` from `str`, because `str` is a `QString` variable while `toUShort()` is from `QByteArray`. So try `str.toLatin1().toHex().prepend("0x").toUShort(&ok,16)`

Comment: Sorry in `QString` there is a function named `toUShort()` but with different meaning. In your case it will convert `A` as a hexadecimal number so the result will be 10 in decimal. For details see [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toUShort) here

Comment: thx han for your help ! i have finally solve my problem with QChar and unicode() function...